# ZVS loss calculation in SIMPLIS

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-losses, llc-converter

Below is the Half-Bridge LLC Converter Example from SIMPLIS.
[image]

I would like to observe the loss from the low side MOSFET.

I want to compare the ZVS and Non-ZVS conditions.

I am curious about why the circuit operating in ZVS condition the power loss in Q2 has a negative spike in there, but there is no negative spike when the circuit operating in non-ZVS condition.

Does anyone know how to explain it?

[image]